# Unable to Install NumPy on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: pi-3, python, pip

I'm installing NumPy on a Raspberry Pi 3 using pip. When I type in `pip install numpy` into the SSH bash terminal, pip starts collecting and downloading NumPy. But when it runs the setup.py file, it just freezes and terminates the SSH connection. Everytime I try to install NumPy, this happens. I'm using Python 2. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

run `sudo apt install python-numpy` (or preferably `sudo apt install python3-numpy` because python2 is terminally ill).

Answer (score 0):

You can not just install anything without a root permission . You must execute this command under root permission. Or you can use use

```
sudo pip install numpy
```

or

```
sudo apt install python-numpy
```

Comment: This is untrue. You CAN install Python packages without sudo - although they are only available to the user

Comment: If you are talking about installing by compiling and using standalone python binary , yes that can work too. But I have never done that

Comment: Thanks, using sudo helped, but I'm not able to use the second command (sudo apt install python-numpy)

Comment: But the hanging problem isn't fixed.